# Email sent using MAPI remains in outbox

Tags: email, outlook, office365, mapi

I am trying to send emails using MAPI by a form application, but the emails are getting stuck in the outbox. I have defined the settings 'Send/Receive' -> Define Send/Receive Groups and checked automatic send/receive every X minutes. But this gets automatically unchecked under All Accounts.

I am using Outlook 2016.
Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by MAPI? Extended MAPI?

Comment: It is just MAPI as per my knowledge, created by powerbuilder "mailSession" object.

Comment: There is Simple MAPI and there is Extended MAPI. PB cannot use Extended MAPI, so that must be Simple MAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as solution to my problem:
Email Accounts -> Double click the account to popup Server Settings -> Uncheck "Use Cached Exchange Mode", not aware of exact reason.
However the "*'Send/Receive' -> Define Send/Receive Groups and checked automatic send/receive every X minutes*" is also necessary.